# Flutter Return API Value to FutureBuilder Null

Tags: api, flutter, listview, dart, mobile

I want to get data from API and convert it List to show it to Mobile, but FutureBuilder always said my data is null. I already print my data it has the data. But when I return it to FutureBuilder it just null.

API Example

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "absence_date": "2021-02-09",
        "time_in": "07:51:34",
        "time_out": "17:14:28"
      },
      {
        "absence_date": "2021-02-08",
        "time_in": "07:53:56",
        "time_out": "17:09:15"
      },
      {
        "absence_date": "2021-02-05",
        "time_in": "07:53:32",
        "time_out": "17:17:31"
      }
    ],
    "last_page": 4
  }
}
```

Attendance.dart -> Model

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Attendance {
  @JsonKey()
  List<dynamic> data;
  @JsonKey()
  int last_page;

  Attendance();

  factory Attendance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AttendanceFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AttendanceToJson(this);
}
```

ListView.dart -> _fecthJobs

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<Job>>(
    future: _fetchJobs(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      print(snapshot.data);
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<Job> data = snapshot.data;
        return _jobsListView(data);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
}

Future<List<Job>> _fetchJobs() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var email = prefs.getString('email');
    await api.attendances(email).then((items) async {
      if (items.success == true) {
        Attendance att = Attendance.fromJson(items.data);
        print(att.data);
        return att.data.map((job) => new Job.fromJson(job)).toList();
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('Exception $e');
  });
}
```

I print att.data, it has the data API, but when it in snapshot.data it say it's null

Comment: replace `print(snapshot.data);` with `print(snapshot);` - what do you see?

Comment: @pskink AsyncSnapshot<List<Job>>(ConnectionState.done, null, null, null)

Comment: ok - do not mix low-level `Future` API (`Future.then` method) and `await` keyword inside `async` method - instead always use `await`

Comment: @pskink
Noted,
Thanks
First time on Flutter

Comment: in your case it should work if you replace `await api.attendances(email).then(...` with `return await api.attendances(email).then(...` but it is a bad solution - instead use `await` only - btw you could also use `return api.attendances(email).then(...`

Comment: yes, it works, but as i said - DO NOT use it that way

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I am just testing it, I know it's bad code for coding it that way

Comment: @pskink Is there any perfect solution to solve my case ?

Comment: see my second comment above: "ok - do not mix low-level Future API (Future.then method) and await keyword inside async method - instead always use await"